# SalesForce community CNAME record

Tags: community, customer-community

We currently have a SalesForce community setup at 21ct.force.com/support

We created a CNAME record (support.21ct.com) that points to 21ct.force.com    When we visit support.21ct.com, we are taken to the normal SalesForce login page, not our community login page.

When I go into our SF Org > Customize > Communities > Manage Communities > Force.com, I notice that the 'Site Primary Custom URL' tick box is not checked.

Does this matter?

What are we doing wrong here? How do we get our CNAME to point to the correct place? SF support has been little help on this.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you do need to enable the 'Site Primary Custom URL' If you want to set a preferred custom URL for authenticated pages and emails that links back to the site or community, then select Site Primary Custom URL.

You can setup a Custom URL for your domain by following the instructions [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_url_add.htm&language=en_US) and then check the above option.